# MySQL: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: mysql-workbench

This is my code:

```
USE sql11690489;
CREATE TABLE Boeken (
    Titel VARCHAR(50),
    Schrijver VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Boeken (Titel, Schrijver)   
VALUES ('Der einzige und sein eigentum', 'Max Stirner');
```

This is the output:

```
Preparing...
'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I tried executing SQL commands to create a table named "Boeken" with columns "Titel" and "Schrijver," and then insert a record into that table. I expected the commands to execute successfully, creating the table and inserting the record without any errors. However, when I attempted to run the code, I received an error message stating "'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'".

Comment: I tried your commands and it worked fine. Is there something else that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: That's a Python error, not MySQL.

Comment: May be a bug with mysql workbench